# Retrieve password value from array

Tags: php, arrays

I am trying to integrate phpass library with an existing authenticate method:

```
public static function authenticate($username, $password)
{
    global $db;
    $username = $db->prep_query($username);
    $password = $db->prep_query($password); // Does not seems like it will be used

    # First step: Retrieve the account based on the user input (email)
    $query_string = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE email = '{$username}' LIMIT 1";
    $query_result = static::find_by_query_string($query_string);

    return !empty($query_result) ? array_shift($query_result) : false;
}
```

Now the record that comes back is ( according to `print_r($query_result)` )

```
Array ( [0] => User Object ( [id] => 7 [password] => $2a$08$qwSjSZ11TUYs5w1L89ppFer2n40HrnjlvaQ00DsUOOvjSYwoEmN4K [email] => test@user.com ) ) 1
```

What I'm trying to retrieve is: `"$2a$08$qwSjSZ11TUYs5w1L89ppFer2n40HrnjlvaQ00DsUOOvjSYwoEmN4K"`

But when I use `$query_result[0][1]` or `$query_result[0]["password]` I'm getting an error.

What am I missing here? How can I use the password value in `$query_string` array ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You access the first array index, which happens to be an object. So you then need to access the property called password.

```
$query_result[0]->password
```

Comment: Thank you! I thought the -> where only used on an object instance. did not I could use it as such.